# Customize Google Chrome keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to customize keyboard shortcuts in Google Chrome.

For example, I would like to map the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to the command "Close Other Tabs" instead of right-clicking on a tab (default command).

Is there any setting in Chrome to set this combination to that command?

Comment: Have you tried searching the Chrome Web Store? If not, here's a link to a shortcuts manager extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck

Comment: @VenkatH Thank you for the hint ! Unfortunately, "Close Other Tabs" is not a command supported by the "Shortkeys" extension, so it does not fill my need.

Comment: Is there a way to remove keyboard shortcuts? I want to use the shortcuts built into Tumblr but it conflicts with the ones already built into chrome and none of the extensions I could find edit already existing ones...

Comment: @wil Almost 3 years later, the "Close Other Tabs" command exists now in Shortkeys.

Comment: Another option is [vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium/wiki/Key-Mappings) although I don't think it can actually rebind `C-W`.

Comment: Ctrl + W is annoying when trying to search within nano on Fedora 26 Web Terminal :-/

Comment: For Windows users looking for an answer that just works, this is the one: [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-shortcut-mana/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd)

Comment: @VenkatH you forgot to mention it is opensource. ;)

Answer (score 128):

If you're on a Mac then you can do this with the Mac `System Preferences`→`Keyboard`→`Shortcuts`. https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/13.0/mac/13.0

Here are my current settings:

[image]

Simplified procedure:

1. Open System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts tab
2. From the left, click App Shortcuts.
3. Click +
4. Choose 'All Applications' as the app
5. Choose 'Shut Down...' as the command
6. Put in whatever shortcut you want.
7. Restart the app you added the shortcut for

Comment: This is great, but unfortunately it did not work with `cmd+shift+c` for some bizarre reason. I wanted to open the javascript console with `cmd+shift+c` instead of `cmd+option+j`

Comment: oh, i get it. u need to know that exact titles from somewhere Oo

Comment: For Windows users, the [AutoControl shortcut manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) extension let's you customize Chrome's shortcuts as well as create your own shortcuts.

Comment: Where can I find a full list of these, e.g. to replace `Cmd+L`?

Comment: @Sinjai the list is from the app menu bar.

Comment: @cmcginty do you know where specifically?

Comment: Don't have any shortcuts for chrome

Comment: Chrome Mac: `Cmd + d` to for `Next Tab to the Right`  didn't work for me.

Comment: This is very useful. However, I want to map "jump to 1st tab" which is `cmd+1` to `ctrl+1`. However it's not in the menu, and I couldn't guess what it is

Comment: @SridharSarnobat It's the bookmark shortcuts by default, you'd better choose another one. e.g., I'd like `cmd+2` for "Select Previous Tab" and `cmd+2` for "Select Next Tab", since `cmd+1` for "Select the 1st Tab" by default (I want set `cmd+4` for "Select the Last Tab" instead of default `cmd+9`, but failed), then I can switch tabs with left hand, and use Trackpad with right hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mac isn't letting me use Command+PgDn and Command+PgUp as shortcut keys :-/

Comment: Looks like this no longer works as of MacOS Sonoma 14.1.2 (23B2091)

Comment: Can the custom hotkeys be exported, or do we need to laboriously set them up each time?

Answer (score 63):

Not entirely the answer for general shortcuts, but still relative and somewhat cumbersome to find, **chrome://extensions/shortcuts** allows you to customize behaviors from a shortcut. I'm sure you could find/make an extension to reroute / transpose all of the shortcuts you want to use to control chrome as you see fit.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty light on the "how"; it's more of a suggestion for an area to investigate in order to create a solution.  Can you flesh it out?  As-is, it would probably be more appropriate as a comment.  [From review](https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/754042)

Comment: This is just for extensions, but it also lets you override built-in shortcuts, like Ctrl + Q.

Comment: Be careful and use the **exact** link: _chrome://extensions/shortcuts_
**Without** http...

Comment: @JoelAZ I found this answer looking for a way to change uBlock Origin extension shortcuts, so yes this answer is useful

Comment: During the process of customizing shortcuts, you need to be aware of what shortcuts are already assigned or designated via extensions. This page will give you that oversight.

Comment: It's also worth saying that the vanilla extensions/shortcuts doesn't allow you to map to keys like "Alt+Tab". To do it, you need to hack it with the console by running something like:

<code>
chrome.developerPrivate.updateExtensionCommand({
    extensionId: "logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck",
    commandName: "03-nexttab",
    keybinding: "Alt+Tab"
});
<code>

Comment: This worked for me with the Shortkeys extension for using Cmd Shift J to move to the next tab in Chome on mac.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 21.04/Chrome 94.0.4606.81, all this does is enable me to create shortcuts to open my extensions.

Comment: This extension helped. The annoying thing about Mac and Chrome, is that you have to use Ctrl Page Up/Down to move around with tabs, but cmd to reopen/close tabs. This disconnect is highly annoying to me, and makes more sense to change the Ctrl to just be cmd. Thank you for this answer, it worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

This has been possible for quite some time already, at least on Windows.
There's a new kind of extensions for Chrome called "native extensions" that can customize Chrome shortcuts and other cool things.

[**AutoControl Shortcut Manager**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) is exactly for this purpose.

There are no restrictions on the shortcuts you can create or customize. You can even disable shortcuts if you assign no action to them.

In the specific case asked in the question, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for closing "other tabs" looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Great extension. However, it's supported from Windows XP to Windows 10. No support for other OSs so far.

Comment: AutoControl Shortcut Manager requires a separate Windows executable installation.  VirustTotal flags that executable as Adware.  No thanks.

Comment: @LesterBuck, I've just checked VirusTotal and it says 6 out 72 engines detected the file. And none of those 6 engines are prominent antivirus solutions. Can you share a link to the VT results you saw?

Comment: @Richt 5/68 now: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/9fcafcd6d615c6dc65389ad0bc81073fa5d8fa02f1d3e5d27b93212a112cd449/detection

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, at least for Windows users.  Finally, I don't have to reach around to press Ctrl+W to close a tab with my right ('navigation') hand (I've added Ctrl+/).

Comment: Amazing project! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It looks like this feature is 'on the way', but it is not in the main release cycle yet. I found an article that describes the feature being implemented in the development build, #22. Or at least partially to allow some features to be shortcut-ed
Ref: *[Create Keyboard Shortcuts for Chrome Extensions](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2012/08/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-chrome.html)*

That post mentions an experimental API for more types of actions linked to shortcuts which can be found.. here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.commands.html

Of course, that's all in the development stage still.

---

This is partially possible with the commands API which has been out for a couple years. http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/commands.html

It's pretty restricted still since you can’t replace the ones that are supplied by the browser and I’m not sure how much is exposed there for things like developer tooling.

Comment: @wil update: this has been in Chrome for some time, just scroll down in the extensions page and click "Keyboard Shortcuts"

Comment: @distilledchaos: That link only allows you to set keyboard shortcuts for apps and extensions, not for the browser in general.

Comment: Going with cVim extension, I guess - I realize that isn't going to be an option for many people, but...it is for me!

Comment: @MikeyE, This is now finally possible through something called "native extensions". Here is one such extension that can customize Chrome's shortcuts once and for all: [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://www.autocontrol.app)

Comment: (how long will it take Google to provide the trivial feature of customizeable keyboard shortcuts...)

Comment: the http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/commands.html link is now broken

Comment: The last two links are broken (404).

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 3 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?

Answer (score 6):

*Update: As of Feb 2017, this plugin is no longer available.*

There is a Chrome plugin called [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) which can do this.

I just used it to create shortkeys for <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to scroll up and down. It also has 'close other windows' available to map to a short-key.

Comment: I installed the plugin, unfortunately for some reason it is impossible to set the combination I want "Ctrl+Shift+W" into the input box (when I try to, the pop-up asking me if I want to leave the page appears).

Comment: This doesn't seem to override the default functionality. I am trying to add a ALT+ENTER ".com" shortcut for the URL bar (for subdomains) and it still uses the default functionality of doing a search.

Comment: I added Ctrl+G to open favorite page , earlier it seemed not working but after restarting chrome it started working. Ctrl+G has default function of searching next in chrome , this extension overrides it.

Comment: This doesn't work for Mac when I try to set "Ctrl+Page Up" to go to the previous tab. (Actually Cmd+Page Up since I switched those two keys)

Comment: You can use the Vimium extension for the `j` `k` scrolling and more.

Comment: The plugin link is 404 now.

Answer (score 5):

Go to this website:
https://www.autocontrol.app/

And download and install their chrome extension, everything is done automatically.

DEAD Simple to add any custom shortcuts from keyboard to mouse.

All u do is add a new function, then click a button, then you tell what this button does on chrome.

Comment: This is currently for Windows only.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the comments of [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/580519/175686), I am also wanting to disable the "Cmd+Shift+W" shortcut for close window, and incidentally the similar shortcut that appears when I disable the first, which now stands for "Close All".

- I simply went to the Mac's Keyboard preference pane, in the "Shortcuts" tab, in "App Shortcuts" section, and went to create new shortcut mappings.
- I made these for Google Chrome and chose that as the first parameter, but I guess you could fix a similar problem in any other application by selecting the one you want instead.
- I then proceeded to name the menu entry that I wanted to replace, such as those I mentioned above.
- Lastly, I assigned it a complex key combination, one that I would hopefully never accidentally press in the future.

It's not the best approach, and I am currently reading into [another question and answer *"How to disable keyboard shortcuts in mac os x"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20692071/1091943) which may remove the shortcut completely, but it works well enough through the existing system interface without having to install any additional software as a limited Google Chrome Web Extension or system application.

Answer (score 4):

The extension in Charley Ramm's answer no longer exists, but I found a different one: [Shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck)

Add to Chrome, press options. I'm using it to bind forward/backwards keys to my Naga Hex V2, which is not supported on linux at the moment. The reviews suggest that some people have problems using it. It works fine for me, Linux Mint 18 + Dell multimedia keyboard.

Restart Chrome after changing the keybindings.

Comment: Shortkeys is nice, but it doesn't work on the new tab page, or when the address bar is in focus

Comment: Shortkeys is discontinued (today being 2021.02.17)

Comment: @DadeMcDade do you have a source for this? The website is still up and the extension available to install. I no longer use Chrome nor the extension so I can't check for myself. I would edit my answer if this is true.

Comment: I can't say that I remember. But you're right - I just checked, and it's available.

Comment: Just installed Shortkeys and it works with NixOS 21.05 and Gnome 4. It also allows to create new tabs, or change the previous tab and next tab shortcuts. To do that, go to: `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` and Shortkeys will have added a bunch of options that can be remapped.

Answer (score 3):

I use [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) on macOS:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [How to Recommend Software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) then [edit] your answer to include at least the minimum required information (the items in **bold**). Posts without this information may be subject to deletion. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple ones working on my Mac:

Simple one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-manager-shortcuts/oofoadncochbkbpebpbndghocapamchi

More options: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts/lplcmnhgijkkmflbmhabnccgelffpnog

Comment: simple and do not need any permission, this rocks and should be the accepted answer, most of the other extensions ask for 1000 permission to change the shortcuts!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to some *high frequency* Chrome shortcuts using by a keyboard, I really recommend you VimiumC. It is an improved version of [Vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium).

Install here: *[Vimium C - All by Keyboard
Vimium C - All by Keyboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium-c-all-by-keyboard/hfjbmagddngcpeloejdejnfgbamkjaeg)*

The source and issue are here:
[Vimium C - All by Keyboard](https://github.com/gdh1995/vimium-c) (GitHub)

[image: Vimium C Options]

- it is so easy to set shortcut to control your chrome, like
  `map <c-w> closeOtherTabs` combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to the command
  "Close Other Tabs"
- and key "z" and "c" made by myself for go left and
  right tab
- and key "s" also made by myself for selected words on
  webpage for Google search in another tab
- VimiumC already set key "x" as close tab and "X" as re-open closed tab by default

It is so convenient, simple and fast, and is all in your fingers.

But, the bad part is, VimiumC can not run on the Chrome safe page, like "`chrome://`" and "`https://chrome.google.com/`" or blank page and unloaded pages which need JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you can remap keys for specific applications (e.g. Chrome) using Microsoft PowerToys - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/

e.g. I swapped my Alt and Ctrl keys for all applications, which broke the Alt+D shortcut in Chrome, so remapped it to Ctrl+L to select the address bar url -

[image: shot]

[image: shot2]

Comment: PowerToys to the rescue to fix bad ui

Answer (score 0):

While I know this isn't the exact solution you were looking for it may be helpful to some as it was to me. This Chrome extension make many advanced shortcuts possible via the use of mouse gestures: [CrxMouse Chrome™ Gestures](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crxmouse-chrome-gestures/jlgkpaicikihijadgifklkbpdajbkhjo/related?hl=en)

Comment: Hi user, welcome to Super User! Questions that are essentially links are discouraged. Can you explain *why* that is the solution, maybe include screen shots of it in action, etc?

Answer (score 0):

https://arc.net/ is a Chromium browser that supports changing shortcuts in its settings.
[image]