# How to add custom keyboard shortcuts to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to dump FireFox for a while since the difference in operating speed compared to Chrome has become too great. But I can't seem to find a way to replicate a feature that is critical to me: being able to open new tabs and make them go directly to a certain address using a keyboard shortcut.

The "famous" extension ShortKeys doesn't seem to work in this latest version of Chrome (58).

There is a question about this regarding Chrome but it's quite old and the answers there are invalid and/or outdated. I need solutions for 2017 :).

Comment: Google Chrome has an option to configure the keyboard shortcuts related to extensions: **chrome://extensions/shortcuts**

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/497526/customize-google-chrome-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

This is really easy to do with [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).  Just write a script that runs while Chrome is open that uses whatever hotkey you want.  All you have to do is send a cntrl-t and the address you want to go to,and enter.

Comment: I also thought about something like this, but unfortunately this is what I'd call a workaround. I'm surprised that either a) the browser doesn't allow developers to do a proper extension or b) that nobody manages to write a working extension to do this. Anyway, I'm a software engineer so I will put AutoHotKey to good use, but I'll leave the question open :)

Comment: @Axonn Somebody cracked it, at last. It's called [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd).

Answer (score 1):

In response to the AHK comment, here's a script that does exactly what you asked.

Even though you consider it a "work around", it works exactly as you wanted. It opens predefined pages in chrome with the use of a hotkey. Who cares which exe handles it?

```
; Only allow 1 instance of the script to run
#SingleInstance, Force
return

; Hotkeys past here only work when chrome.exe is the active window.
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe

; Press F1 while in chrome...
F1::
    ; To run chrome at the specified address.
    Run, % "chrome.exe https://superuser.com/questions/1212547/how-to-add-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-to-chrome/"
return

; Press F2 while in chrome...
F2::
    ; Open a new tab.
    Send, ^t
    Sleep, 100

    ; And then send this reddit's AHK help forum, plus the enter key, to the address bar.
    SendInput, www.reddit.com/r/autohotkey{Enter}

; Hotkeys past this will work globally
#IfWinActive
```